# How to pass parameter on [WebMethod] through POST request

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, webmethod

I'm trying to pass the `params` "hello" to the `[WebMethod]`. However, for unknown reason it returns an error of `Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'data'`. Why is that? In which part is the error?

Web service

`[WebMethod]
 public string GetData(string data)
 { return "success"; }`

Javascript

```
  $http.post("somelocation/PostData",{ //Edited: FROM GetData to PostData
     headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json;"
     }, 
     params:{data:"hello"},
     data:{}
  }
```

Comment: In the post, you are passing an object; in the service, you are expecting a string.

Comment: @rfornal that's not really relevant due to internal data processing done by `$http`

Comment: Is this going to be a GET or POST operation? your naming is a bit confusing.  You might be better suited using `$resource` if you are reading and writing data

Comment: Ohh, I am so sorry 'bout my naming convention. It's a POST operation, just.. don't mind the naming convention. So sorry, I'll take that as a tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` is for setting query string in a url , use `data` option for post data. See $http docs for further detail

Comment: Also note you have several typos in you `content-type`

Comment: Now it's working. Thank you, Sir! Thank you for the tip too, 'bout reading $http docs. cheers